# Evernote Sandbox Oauth not working suddenly

Tags: evernote

I'm using https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-php for my app. The Oauth process on my sandbox server was working perfectly fine, until today. The weird thing is, on the live server, its currently working perfectly fine.

Any ideas appreciated. Heres the code

```
    $sandbox = env('EVERNOTE_SANDBOX');

    $china   = env('EVERNOTE_CHINA');

    $callbackurl = env('APP_URL');

    $oauth_handler = new \Evernote\Auth\OauthHandler($sandbox, false, $china);

    $key      = 'my key';
    $secret   = 'my secret ';
    $callback = $callbackurl.'/api/connect';

    try {
        $oauth_data  = $oauth_handler->authorize($key, $secret, $callback);
    error_log(print_r($oauth_data,true));

    }
```

Changing $sandbox = true doesn't change anything.

the error log at the end shows this.

```
    [08-Mar-2019 08:38:00 UTC] Evernote\Auth\OauthHandler Object
    (
[sandbox:protected] => 1
[china:protected] => 
[consumer_secret:protected] => [censored]
[token_secret:protected] => 
[supportLinkedSandbox:protected] => 
[params:protected] => Array
    (
        [oauth_callback] => http://server_ip_address/api/connect
        [oauth_consumer_key] => [censored]
        [oauth_nonce] => [censored]
        [oauth_signature] => 
        [oauth_signature_method] => HMAC-SHA1
        [oauth_timestamp] => 1552034280
        [oauth_version] => 1.0
    )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with a exit(); after

$oauth_data  =.......
exit();